# Unity3D: My shader doesn't work well in GameView

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I wrote SurfaceShader with bumped texture.

I apply my material to a sphere. I can see the sphere **in Scene View**, but I can't see the sphere **in Game View.**

When I apply other shaders to the sphere, I can see the sphere in GameView.
[image]
[image]

I found [the same question](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/should-a-bumped-diffuse-shader-show-up-in-the-game-view-or-unity-remote.108109/) in Unity Community.

I understood I should use not Vertex Lighting but Pixel Lighting.

But I couldn't understand which settings should I change. Should I modify my shader or my settings?

My shader is the following.

```
Shader "Custom/MyShader2"{
    Properties{
        _Bump("Bump",2D) = "white"{}
        _DiffuseColor("Diffuse Color", Color) = (1.0,1.0,1.0)
        _Specular("Specular",Range(1.0,50.0)) = 15.0
        _Alpha("Alpha",Range(0,1)) = 1
    }
    SubShader{
        Tags{
            "RenderType" = "Opaque"
        }
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Original alpha
        struct Input{
            float4 color: COLOR;
            float2 uv_Bump;
        };
        float3 _DiffuseColor;
        float _Specular;
        sampler2D _Bump;
        float _Alpha;
        half4 LightingOriginal( SurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half3 viewDir, half atten) {
            half diff = max(0,dot(s.Normal,lightDir));
            half spec = max(0,dot(s.Normal,normalize(lightDir + viewDir)));
            spec = pow(spec, _Specular);
            half trans = 1.0 - max(0,dot(s.Normal, viewDir)) + spec;
            half4 c;
            c. rgb = (s.Albedo * _LightColor0.rgb * diff + _LightColor0.rgb * spec / 2) * (atten * 2);
            c.a = trans;
            return c;
        }
        void surf( Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            o.Albedo = _DiffuseColor * _Alpha;;
            o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Bump,IN.uv_Bump));
            o.Alpha = _Alpha;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
```

with

```
Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
Cull Off ZWrite Off
```

Comment: Thank you for your first answer. But I can't solve　the problem by changing shader.